# Facebook canvas iframe and security

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

I want to open my small platform to developers, so they can build applications that could be inserted in our site as iframe. Similar as facebook is doing, but no, I am not trying to build another Facebook:). From what I understand developers can build facebook application using iframe.

**Question:** I am wondering how is about security from facebook user perspective. How Facebook prevent that application developer doesn't put malware javascript code inside iframe. I haven't noticed any automatically mechanism that prevent including something like that in iframe.

tnx

Comment: Can you give any examples of what you are worried about a third party trying todo?

Comment: They can put malware javascript code inside iframe to attack user computer via browser. I am not sure how FB prevent this because canvas iframe application could be developed by anybody.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a problem at all, I think you are worrying for nothing.

There are no security issues that you need to worry about yourself, the loaded page in the iframe is sandboxed, and is "guarded" by the browser.
The two iframes can't even communicate with one another since they are not sharing the same domain, and modern browsers will block any attempt to execute javascript code in another frame if the two frames have different domain.

The thing that facebook did was to workaround that problem, each iframe app in facebook loads the [facebook javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) which then enables the nested iframe to make requests to facebook and be notified (by callbacks) when the data returns.

As for "malware javascript code inside iframe to attack user computer via browser", the iframe has the same exact security policies enforced by the browser as any other browser page, if someone manages to somehow bypass those policies then it has little difference where it's loaded, and facebook are not enforcing any other security measures.

The only thing you need to worry about is that scripts inside the iframe will be able to access your scripts and/or dom, which should not happen unless you create a machnism which will let them (somehow bypass the cross-domain policy).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not sure if I understand you. You said: "and modern browsers will block any attempt to execute javascript code in another frame if the two frames have different domain." Simple test if I put into my page <iframe src="http://www.arabiacooking.com/example.html"></iframe> this execute alert('1'). So javascript is not blocked.

I am not talking about two iframes. I am talking if I put single iframe (a developer application) inside our page.

Comment: And since developer has free hands how to build application and then hosted on his site and putting it inside our site inside iframe, they can put some malware javascript code. This is what I am worried because iframe will shown in our site, even if not hosted in our site. I am not worried about communication between iframe and our page. This won't happen. They will communicate only via api request inside their application.

Comment: I wrote that the js in the iframe won't be able to communicate with the top frame, something like: *parent.someFunction()* will be blocked. Obviously normal js code will be ok inside the iframe, but that should not worry you since there's nothing they can do. The security "hazards" that are "available" for the page in the iframe are exactly the same as in any page, and are not your concern but of the browser developers and security experts.

Comment: Tnx for explanation. But still I think that it should be my worry. Because iframe will be inside our site. And if malware javascript code is inside iframe than this is bad for our site. Yes, exactly the same as in any page. But for exception that normally you control what you put on your page and you don't put any malware code if you care about your users. But in this case we can not know what will be inside iframe which will be actually part of our site. Normall user won't know if this is iframe, they will simple think it is our site because they will actually access iframe inside our page.

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way: you have no way to control what is loaded in the iframe. It's that simple. Facebook used to load apps in a different way before they used the iframe solution, it was called FBML and used something called FBJS which was subset of javascript (kinda). They actually loaded the content from your server themselves, parsed it to make sure it's valid and rendered it to the user. In such a way you can in fact control things but it's way to complicated to actually consider as an option.